# buid failed on git push ionic master

Tags: git, bash, ionic-framework

Unfortunately, I cannot build my app on push ionic master in order to test on real device. However, when I do ionic serve everything is running smoothly. I tried to delete plugins, node module and run npm install, but still I get the same error. Maybe somebody can support me. here is the log:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.0 (0118d89)
  on ip-10-2-65-246 (c9648220)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-10-2-65-246...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/c9648220/2/project-1'...
Checking out d227630e as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ run "fetch-updates"
Running Stage fetch-updates for Job: 5281890
Checking for build process updates...
$ run "build-app"
Running Stage build-app for Job: 5281890
Parsing ionic.config.json for project settings
Project Settings:
    Name: Ionic2WooMultiStore
    App ID: 4a03542a
    Type: ionic-angular
Build script detected in package.json...
$ npm install --quiet --no-optional
up to date in 5.928s
$ npm install --quiet --no-optional success
$ npm run build
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.2.1
npm info lifecycle ionic-woo-store@~prebuild: ionic-woo-store@
npm info lifecycle ionic-woo-store@~build: ionic-woo-store@

> ionic-woo-store@ build /usr/src/app
> ionic-app-scripts build

sh: 1: ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied
npm info lifecycle ionic-woo-store@~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! ionic-woo-store@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-woo-store@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-02-04T14_12_58_990Z-debug.log
npm run build failed
Running after script...
$ run "clean-up"
Running Stage clean-up for Job: 5281890
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
TermsPrivacy Policy© 2017 Drifty Co.  v0.0.454
IonicDocsBlogHelp & SupportStatus
```